# Reducing an array of objects to key value map

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects. I need to make an object so that I can fetch the name based on an id.

```
const drinks = [
  { _id: "5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6c", name: "Americano", __v: 0 },
  { _id: "5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6d", name: "Latte", __v: 0 },
  { _id: "5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6e", name: "Flat White", __v: 0 }
];
```

I tried this which almost works:

```
console.log(drinks.reduce(
  (accumulator, currentValue) => 
     Object.assign(accumulator, accumulator[currentValue._id] = currentValue.name), {}));
```

However it outputs:

```
Object { 
  0: "F", 1: "l", 2: "a", 3: "t", 4: " ", 5: "W", 6: "h", 7: "i", 8: "t", 9: "e",
  5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6c: "Americano", 
  5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6d: "Latte", 
  5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6e: "Flat White" 
}
```

I need:

```
Object { 
  5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6c: "Americano", 
  5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6d: "Latte", 
  5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6e: "Flat White"
}
```

Why is my function also breaking down one of the values into characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const drinks = [{ _id: "5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6c", name: "Americano", __v: 0 },
                { _id: "5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6d", name: "Latte", __v: 0 },
                { _id: "5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6e", name: "Flat White", __v: 0 }];
                
                const result=drinks.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
                acc[curr._id]=curr.name;
                return acc;
                },{})
                
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can map your array into an array of *entries* (key / value pairs) which you can then run through [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create the final object

```js
const drinks = [
  { _id: "5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6c", name: "Americano", __v: 0 },
  { _id: "5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6d", name: "Latte", __v: 0 },
  { _id: "5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6e", name: "Flat White", __v: 0 }
]
                
const result = Object.fromEntries(drinks.map(({ _id, name }) =>
  [ _id, name ]))
  
console.log(result)
```

The longer version would be something like this

```js
const result = drinks.reduce((obj, { _id, name }) => ({
  ...obj, // spread syntax is like `Object.assign()`
  [ _id ]: name // use `_id` as a dynamic object key with value `name`
}), {})
```

---

The issue with your current code is that the result of...

```js
accumulator[currentValue._id] = currentValue.name
```

is the value assigned (ie `currentValue.name`). When used as an argument in `Object.assign()`, it is broken down as object entries, thus resulting in what you're seeing with

```js
{ 
  0: "F", 
  1: "l", 
  2: "a", 
  3: "t", 
  4: " ", 
  5: "W", 
  6: "h", 
  7: "i", 
  8: "t", 
  9: "e"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining what's going on!

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the object `{ [currentValue._id]: currentValue.name }` to `assign` instead of assignment `accumulator[currentValue._id] = currentValue.name`

```js
const drinks = [
  { _id: "5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6c", name: "Americano", __v: 0 },
  { _id: "5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6d", name: "Latte", __v: 0 },
  { _id: "5fe40ad4d2e6e6de85c46a6e", name: "Flat White", __v: 0 }
];

console.log(drinks.reduce(
  (accumulator, currentValue) => 
     Object.assign(accumulator, { [currentValue._id]: currentValue.name }), {}));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is closest to what I was trying to achieve

Answer (score -2):

This will work

```
drinks.map(({ _id, name }) => ({
  [_id]: name
}))
```

Comment: This will output an array of objects, not a single object...